# Looking for an ExpressionEngine addon like this

Tags: ee2, add-on

I'm looking for an ExpressionEngine addon that can do the following:

1. have a short form that allows a file to be uploaded, form will include date, etc.
2. based on the template the file should automatically be tagged for easy retrieval

Sounds rather simple, but I'm not sure if I'll need a combination of addons or if I'm missing built in features.

**Edited to better state my question. See below.**

Basically a document retrieval system with tags so that it makes it easier to find and retrieve given documents.

Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest editing your question title to reflect your needs rather than a generic topic. I think you'll get more help that way.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to achieve this by creating an "Uploads" channel with your required date and other fields. Add a file upload field to it too.

I'm not sure what you mean by "tagged. If you mean that this will be uploaded from the front end then you could add a "template" field to the channel and then in the form make that a hidden field containing whatever tag you need (such as the template name).